# Adding an array of structs into a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have a code where I am able to add my struct array to a file, but am unable to continue adding contacts to my struct array like I should.

Here are my variables:

```
struct contact {                // Data structure that holds contact information 
    char FirstName[10];         // Array for first name
    char LastName[10];          // Array for last name
    int PhoneNum;               // Phone number
};

int Choice = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int size = 1;
    struct contact *con = (struct contact *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct contact));
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int SortChoice = 0;
    int iRandNum = 0;
    int Valid = 0;
    char temp[10];
    int tempNum = 0;
    char File[20];
    int status = 0;

    FILE *pRead;
    FILE *pWrite;
```

Here is the add contact part:

```
if (n == size)
            {
                size = size * 2;
                con = (struct contact*)realloc(con, size * sizeof(struct contact));
            }
            // Records the information given into the structure
            printf("\nYou chose to add a contact.");
            printf("\nFirst name: ");
            scanf("%s", con[n].FirstName);
            printf("\nLast name: ");
            scanf("%s", con[n].LastName);
            printf("\nPhone number (Numbers only): ");
            scanf("%d", &con[n].PhoneNum);
            printf("\nRecord added to the phone book.");

            // Prints out the given information
            printf("\n\nNew contact:");
            printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[n].FirstName);
            printf("\nLast name: %s", con[n].LastName);
            printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[n].PhoneNum);
            printf("\nContact number is %d", n);
            printf("\n");
            n += 1;
```

And here is the file part:

```
printf("\nYou chose to store all contacts to a file.");

            if (status == 0){
                printf("\nWhat would you like to name your file?\n");
                scanf("%s", &File);
                printf("\nFile name is %s", File);
                pWrite = fopen(File, "w");

                if (pWrite == 0){
                    printf("\nFile not opened");
                }
                else {
                    for (a = 0; a < n; a++){
                        fwrite(&con[a], sizeof(struct contact), 1, pWrite);
                    }
                    fclose(pWrite);
                    pRead =fopen(File, "r");
                    printf("\n\nContacts added to %s", File);
                    printf("\n\nContacts in file:\n");
                    while (fread(&con[a], sizeof(struct contact),1, pRead)){
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("\nFirst name: %s", con[a].FirstName);
                        printf("\nLast name: %s", con[a].LastName);
                        printf("\nPhone number: %d", con[a].PhoneNum);
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                    fclose(pRead);
                }
            }
```

If you guys can figure out where I've gone wrong, and potentially why I can't continue to access the file I created that would be great. Thanks

Comment: What is the line of the code which causes the seg fault?

Comment: you should also paste the definitions

Comment: `fwrite(&con[a],..` is an error. Remove the `&`.

Comment: Besides, `n` is still zero in the code shown, so nothing will be written.

Comment: My problem was that I had not open pRead. Thank you xing

Comment: @CatyBattjes __always__ check if `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct contact *con = (struct contact *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct contact));`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast

Comment: OT: regarding: ` while (fread(&con[a], sizeof(struct contact),1, pRead)){`  Always check the returned value (compare against the third parameter) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (not just code snippets so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it

Comment: OT: regarding `scanf("%s", con[n].LastName);` (and other calls to `scanf()`)  1) always check the returned value (in this instance it should be 1 (any other value indicates an error occurred)  to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: `fread(&con[a], sizeof(struct contact),1, pRead)` reads everything into the same place (`a` never changes in the loop). On top of that, the value of `a` at the time of reading is `n`, which is likely illegal.